# How to pass port mapping dynamically to the docker-compose up command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers

I have two container images and doing compose and running the docker using "**docker-compose up -d**".
This works fine. I want to run the same container image in another port say 8081.
Can we pass port mapping as a command line parameter docker-compose up -port novnc :8081:8080?
How to pass port mapping dynamically to the docker-compose up command?

```
version: '2'
services:
  ide:
    image: myApp
    image: myImage:latest
    environment:
      - DISPLAY=novnc:0.0
    depends_on:
      - novnc
    networks:
      - x11
  novnc:
    image: myImageTwo:latest
    environment:
      - DISPLAY_WIDTH=1600
      - DISPLAY_HEIGHT=968
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - x11
networks:
  x11:
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use a ${VAR} in your docker-compose.yml

e.g.

```
version: '2'
services:
  apache:
    image: httpd:2.4
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
    ports:
      - ${APP_PORT}:80
```

then use environment variable:

```
$ export APP_PORT=8080
$ docker-compose up
```

or inline version:

```
$ APP_PORT=8080 docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but it recreating the image. I want to run multiple containers with same image with different port numbers as like docker run.

Comment: I have tried, it doesn't recreate container, there may be some other reason cause recreating.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it using the `.env` file.
For example, you'll have something like this :

```yaml
$ cat .env
TAG=v1.5

$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:${TAG}"
```

In the example, you can see that the tag value is in a variable that is set in the env file.

You can find out more in the [official doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with-an-env-file)

Answer (score 1):

Change your ports section to:

```
    ports:
      - "${MY_PORT}:8080"
```

and then just use `MY_PORT=8081 docker-compose up -d`

Answer (score 1):

you can also use a port range

```
ports:
  - "8080-8081:8080"
```

so you don't have to pass as parameter